# Node.js alone or as a companion to another server tool

Tags: php, javascript, html, node.js, websocket

For my final year project at University I'm going to be creating an application which will use Node.js to send messages to update the position of a set of elements on the screen.

**Detailed description of my goal:**

A user should be able to create a room, a room can contain custom widgets such as pictures, ideas, music and video.

Other users should be able to view this users room, and comment on these widgets, like them, tweet about them etc. All widgets are movable and have an x,y coordinate and this will be broadcast every time an element is moved (using websockets).

A widget can be deleted or edited by the owner, this will update the element (once again websockets).

There will also be a built in chat feature to allow users to talk (in real time, using web sockets).

*The widget details will be stored in a database*

There is more functionality which isn't relevant to web sockets so I've omitted it.

**The following image demonstrates what i'm building**:  (sorry about the size!)
http://jtbrown.me.uk/assets/unrelated/mindcloud.jpg

**I've really only got two questions:**

1. Would I be better off using node on its own? (I'm not experienced in server side JavaScript)
2. Is it feasible to combine it with another web server such as Zend?

Comment: For simplicity I would highly recommend you to learn JS and use node on its own. Only if you have strict deadlines should you only use node for the socket.io part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in node alone, but maybe you want to use a basic web–framework based on node to make things a bit easier and to save time and work. I would recommend looking into [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) or maybe even [Zappa](https://github.com/mauricemach/zappa) (based on ExpressJS) if you want to try out the excellent [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/).

Comment: I'm more experienced in PHP, I was hoping to use Node.js to handle a couple of events. I would like to run the rest of the website on a linux web server. Would it be possible to do this?

Comment: @JackBrown sure, you can do both. You will need some kind of shared data store though

Comment: @Raynos do you have a recommendation for the shared data store and how I could implement it? Maybe MongoDB?

Comment: @jackBrown  I would recommend redis, there are modules for both node & PHP

Comment: Jack, sure you can do this.  Hell, I've done this.  I used Node.js as my front-end, and couch as my back-end.  Think of your "room" as a single couch document, and your objects as elements of the document; you pass it back and forth between server and client, or sub-elements of it, with RESTful urls for each possible "ticket specifying a change."  (See the Richardson Maturity Model for details.)  All of the chatting and social integration stuff is transient; no need to keep it.  With [Zappa](http://thechangelog.com/post/1582034775/zappa-razor-sharp-dsl-for-modern-web-apps), it would be easy.

Comment: @JackBrown use redis to share data real fast, using for example Redis's pubsub